# angularJS UI tab print selected contend from tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have nested angularJS tabs and my problem is I want to be able to print the select content list  whatever user selected from parent and child tabs. when user click print list it print all page ? 
http://plnkr.co/edit/8iYDDRaGHi2iNm0MWGfL?p=preview

```
$scope.printEmployeeList = function (divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=700');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: for example if user select this tab Edinburg and detail 1 when user click print it should print detail 1 not all page

Comment: Its really hard to pretend that, as you showing all the tabs..I'd suggest that you should go for ui-router which does provide a good feature over the partials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a directive on button click and it will give you the the content of selected tab.

**Markup**

```
<button print-content="content">Employee List</button>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('printContent', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function(event) {
        console.log($document.find('#'+ attrs.printContent).find('.tab-pane.active').html());
        //you code add your print code here
      });
    }
  }
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/eWc7RtYF2MXpLay5mkB8?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you can print the content by moving the button to child tab and warp the content you want to print by using div tag it will be print it 
see  this plunker 
http://embed.plnkr.co/tB1lUvIsL3TS8LGYmnCk/preview