# Print a distant page in JS, JQ, or Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, printing

I have pages that I have to print, but when I launch printing, the preview is ugly and I can't select and modify the elements I want (there's only few elements I want to print, and others that I hide only for the printing).

I don't succeed to do it with less (with `@media print`), so I made a template and I inject inside it the elements I want to show for the printing (with AngularJS). The problem is that the original page is something like `http://example.com/id/page-name/?tab=media`. But I put in my script a listener which catch the print event and redirect the user on `http://example.com/id/page-name/?tab=media&print=true`.

Then a timeout launches the printing script (`window.print()`), and when the user leave the printing page, the script redirects him to `http://example.com/id/page-name/?tab=media`.

The problem is that it makes a lot of closing/opening windows, and it may be uncomfortable for the user.
I think my solution is weird and awkward, but I found nothing else to do it...

So do you have a solution to print a distant page, which will not make a lot of closing/opening frames?

For example, when I `Ctrl+P` on `http://example.com/id/page-name/?tab=media`, it prints the `http://example.com/id/page-name/?tab=media&print=true` page, and not the original ?

A thing like `document.location.href="http://example.com/id/page-name/?tab=media&print=true".print();` or `print('http://example.com/id/page-name/?tab=media&print=true');` ?

I hope it's possible!

Answer (score 1):

you can get some idea from this question [angularJS UI tab print selected contend from tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567205/angularjs-ui-tab-print-selected-contend-from-tab) and create print function like

```
  $scope.print = function (divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=700');
    popupWin.document.open()
    popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Comment: Very nice idea, I don't think about this logic before. I'll try it, and see if it works perfectly for me. Thank you for this answer!

Comment: I thought about a problem with this solution : if the user has an ad-blocker, it will block the print popup. The problem is that all navigators blocks the popups windows too.